# react-table dynamic columns without accessors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-table

I want to iterate over an object and made columns according to this object because logic and appearance of those columns is the same

```
const customColumns = myObject.map(item =>  {
    return {
    Header: '111',
    headerClassName: "excel-table-header-class",
    className: "excel-table-row-class",
    width: 100
}});
```

Later I'll change header dynamically.

The issue is I cannot enable all those columns.

Among other columns I use

```
           columns={[ ..., customColumns ]}
```

and this won't go.

I can do

```
           columns={[ ..., customColumns[0] ]}
```

And it is ok, I see my single column, but I want to display all the columns, not the one.

Later I want to use something like

```
   const customColumns = () => {
        const {myObject} = props;
        if (myObject !== undefined && myObject.length !== 0) {
            myObject.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    {
                        Header: 'C2',
                        headerClassName: "excel-table-header-class",
                        className: "excel-table-row-class",
                        width: 100,                                        
                                 });
                              });
                            }
                          };
```

but in this case I cannot even display a single column like customColumns[0]. Why that's happening?

Answer (score 0):

I described all columns in different arrays and used in columns={} concat method, that worked for me.